# Emulate IE7 in IE9. What is the default?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm currently working on a site that has uses the Emulate IE7 meta tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

As far as I know and as far as I've googled this tag also addresses IE9, forcing it to go into IE7 compatibility mode.

However I noticed that one of the devs on the project is viewing the page in IE9-mode, not in compatibility mode.

How does this work? Is compatibility mode the default setting in IE9, when the Emulate IE7 meta tag is set? Would one have to manually change a setting in IE9 to bypass the Emulate IE7 meta tag?

Answer (score 3):

The Developer Toolbar in IE9 (and IE8) allows you to change the browser mode-- including forcing display using the IE9 rendering engine.

For more information, read this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd565628(VS.85).aspx#browsermodes